# Run C# Nunit tests in ci/cd process in jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit, winappdriver

I have a c# nunit test project that use winappdriver tool for running and simulates user activities like buttons clicks, send keys on windows desktop application. to run the test with winappdriver it is needed to open an Appium session. what's the best way of doing that using Jenkins jobs?

I tried to run the tests using Jenkins pipeline but only the test that are not using the winappdriver run successfully. I got some errors relating to the Appium isn't recognized in the Jenkins environment but haven't managed to overcome them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.